# I understood the code but not the mentioned options

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I was asked a question whose answer were in options. We need to chose 2 options (multiple selection question type). The question was "Which two statements will successfully invoke this procedure ?". Correct options were (I am not mentioning other wrong ones though):

1. `Execute upd_bat_stat;`
2. `Execute upd_bat_stat(v_ab=gt;10,v_id=gt;31);`

The first one I opted is correct but second one I did not opted. I opted something else.
And I am not getting this coding of second one. Can anyone tell me the meaning of second option ? What is 'gt' here ?

```
     create or replace procedure upd_bat_stat(v_id IN number default 10, 
                                              v_ab IN number default 4)
     is
     begin
        update player_bat_stat
        set at_bats = at_bats + v_ab
        where player_id = v_id;
        commit;
     end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML the symbols `&gt;` is translated to `>`. So the second sentence is to be understood as:

```
Execute upd_bat_stat(v_ab => 10, v_id => 31);
```

Of course that's one of the standard way to call a procedure in PL/SQL, for instance:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(dbms_random.value(low => 0, high => 10));
  3  END;
  4  /

1.8144949728486423597614495316809370386
```

For further reading: [Positional, Named, and Mixed Notation for Actual Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00825)

Since 11gR2, you can also use named parameters in SQL:

```
SQL> select dbms_random.value(low => 0, high => 10) res from dual;

RES
----------------------------
5.68503743363485069064449316
```

Comment: +1 After reading this, you've explained it much better than I did :)

Comment: Thanks :). It was such a simple question if I would have decoded it.